# mysql nested select in update

Tags: mysql, sql, nested

Good morning,

I have a problem updating my Database.

This is my `orders` table:

```
id | parent_id | type | paid
```

Now I need to update all orders where the parent_id is paid. I have a little trouble doing this, because of nested queries.

I tried something like this

```
UPDATE orders
SET orders.paid = NOW()
WHERE (
    SELECT orders.parent_id
    FROM orders
    WHERE orders.id = orders.parent_id
)
```

But this won't do the magic.
Can't get into this :/

```
1 | NULL | 8 | 2015-20-09 12:00:00
2 | 1    | 7 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
3 | 1    | 7 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
4 | NULL | 8 | 2015-18-09 12:00:00
5 | 4    | 7 | 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

Comment: Update to what when parent_id is paid ? Please provide some sample data and expected result after the update command.

Comment: Update to just current datetime, I added some sample records

Comment: So you basically want to update all rows? Or just rows related to one specific order?

Comment: `Now I need to update all orders where the parent_id is paid.` is that `paid` column is not `0000-00-00 00:00:00` ?

Comment: I want to update all "sub"-orders where the parent is paid.

Comment: But what defines if its paid or not ?

Comment: If the datetime is different then 0000-00-00 00:00:00. Just rudimental decision

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use JOIN for doing the update something as

```
update orders o1
join orders o2 on o2.id = o1.parent_id
set o1.paid = now()
where o2.paid <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```